# Cytoscape 3.7.2 does not work in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: ubuntu, cytoscape

After upgrading from `Ubuntu 18.04` to `Ubuntu 19.10`, I can't open previous `.cys` files or use `Cytoscape 3.7.2`. Here is the result of the script checker. It let me know that `Cytoscape 3.7.2` and `Ubuntu 19.10` are not compatible and it seems this is a Java issue. Has anyone tried to fix this? Thank you

[image: This is the Terminal prompt after running the script checker available on the Cytoscape web site]

Answer (score 1):

I just answered this on the Cytoscape-helpdesk.  For completeness, here is what I suggested:

1. Try to install a copy of Java 8 from somewhere.  Our experience with
   OpenJDK 8 on Linux has been somewhat spotty, but other than things
   that use JavaFX it seems to work.
2. Update your Java to OpenJDK 11 and give the Cytoscape 3.8 release
   candidate a try.  There are some known bugs, so this won't be the
   final version, but it certainly works for most things.  You can find
   the release candidate here:
   https://cytoscape-builds.ucsd.edu/cytoscape-builds/Cytoscape-3.8.0/3.8.0-Release-Candidate-2/

-- scooter